# Fetch specific fields on a hasMany relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a **hasMany** relation function like this:

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
}
```

And use it like this:

```
$data = \App\User::with('articles')->get();
```

I don't have any problems with it, since it's returning the expected data. Something like this:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Jhon",
"lastname": "Doe",
"articles": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Article 1",
        "status": "published",
        "published_at": "2015-04-30"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Article 2",
        "status": "draft",
        "published_at": null
    }
 ]
}
```

What I am trying to achieve but I still can't it's to fetch just a subset of the relation's fields to obtain this:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Jhon",
"lastname": "Doe",
"articles": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Article 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Article 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

My intention is to find a way to specify the subset of fields in the Model's function instead of  iterating the returning collection and unset the unwanted fields.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You've got a couple options.

****NB**: For options 1 and 2 below, the foreign key (`user_id`) must be selected so that Laravel knows how to link the models together when building the relationships.*

1. Modify the relationship query when using it. The `with()` method can accept an array of key/value pairs where the key is the name of the relationship and the value is a Closure that modifies the relationship query.

   ```
    $data = \App\User::with(['articles' => function($query) {
        // user_id is required here*
        $query->select(['id', 'title', 'user_id']);
    }])->get();
   ```
2. Create a new relationship that contains the fields you want.

   ```
    public function articleTitles() {
        // user_id is required here*
        return $this->hasMany('App\Article')->select(['id', 'title', 'user_id']);
    }

    $data = \App\User::with('articleTitles')->get();
   ```
3. If you're only concerned about the array/json output, you can modify the App\Article model to only display the id and title when converted to an array.

   ```
    class Article extends Model {
        protected $visible = ['id', 'title'];
    }
   ```

What you choose depends on what you need.

Comment: I had previously tried option 2 without success because it returned empty in "articles". Today I tried option 1 and also returned empty in " articles". I tried $query->orderBy('id', 'asc'); and works but with the "select" method isn't working.

Comment: @Tony When using options 1 or 2, you must make sure that you've included the foreign key in the select statement ('id'), otherwise Laravel won't know how to link the objects together and your articles attribute will always be empty.

Comment: That was the piece that made it work! After your comment, I did it like this:

    `return $this->hasMany('App\Article')->select(['id', 'title', 'user_id']);`

That foreign_key was the answer. Thanks @patricus

Comment: I tried it and why always return empty array? any new solution for laravel 5.6?

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur check the NB "For options 1 and 2 above, the foreign key (user_id) must be selected so that Laravel knows how to link the models together when building the relationships."

Answer (score 20):

```php
<?php
$data = \App\User::with('articles:id,title,user_id')->get();
```

`user_id` is important in **hasMany** relationships

Comment: You are live saver man, // *user_id is important in hasmay relationships (great Man).  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I want to highlight the problem:
when you want to select certain fields in Laravel relation then you should pass the primary_key in the select in order to get the data instead of null!