# Laravel : HasMany relationship returns null data when added select query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I am facing a problem to return a selected column data using `hasMany` relationship. I've two tables
`loadbooking`,`loadbooking_packages`. Where `loadbooking_packages` have `loadbooking_id` (Reference of loadbooking) id.

So in my `loadbooking` Model I've set relation :

```
public function LoadbookingPackages()
{
    return $this->HasMany(LoadbookingPackage::class,'loadbooking_id');
}
```

It returns all columns data. But when I'm trying to return selected columns with select it returns null.
I've tried :

```
public function LoadbookingPackages()
{
    return $this->HasMany(LoadbookingPackage::class,'loadbooking_id')->select('id', 'packagetype_id');
}
```

How can I solved this ?

Comment: Have you tried addSelect() method instead of select? https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#selects

Comment: No it is not working.@ShahadatHossain

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30218621/9193055) answer should solve your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch specific fields on a hasMany relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022038/fetch-specific-fields-on-a-hasmany-relation)

Comment: In most cases when you select specific fields using `select` you should specify the `ids` of both related tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please keep stable

```
public function LoadbookingPackages()
{
    return $this->HasMany(LoadbookingPackage::class,'loadbooking_id');
}
```

Usages:

```
$loadbooking->load('loadbookingPackages:id, packagetype_id');
$loadbooking->loadbookingPackages;
```